# JQuery scanning nested elements iteratively

Tags: jquery, xml, recursion

I am trying to use JQuery to iterate over nested nodes in an XML document which I have read in and converted to a JQuery object. In XML form it looks something like:

```
<Nodes>
  <Node attrib="tree">
    <Node attrib="tree" att2="something">
      <Node attrib="leaf" att2="somethingelse"></Node>
    </Node>
  <Node attrib="leaf" att2="somethingmore"></Node>
   </Node>
<Nodes>
```

I actual want to perform a function for each Node with attrib="leaf". Node elements can be nested at any level up to perhaps 10.

I've found various recursive methods using .each but cannot get them to iterate. Without selecting particular attributes I tried this sort of thing based on some great examples here but cannot quite see it. ViewData.nodeTree is the loaded XML JQquery object
 of the above XML.

```
    $.each(ViewData.nodeTree, function (key, val) {
        recursiveFunction(key, val);
    });
    function recursiveFunction(key, val) {
        actualFunction(key, val);
        var value = val['Node'];
        if(value instanceof Object) {
            $.each(value, function (key, val) {
                recursiveFunction(key, val);
            });
        }
    }
    function actualFunction(key, val) {
        alert(key + " " + val);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this approach wouldn't work:

```
$(ViewData.nodeTree).find('Node[attrib="leaf"]').each(function () {
    // do something on the node
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/B25vF/

No recursion necessary.

Comment: Thanks - looks obvious looking at it but spent most of th evening puzzling it out.